# Working file structure for deploying existing nodejs/express app to Firebase Functions?

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-functions

I am ready to deploy my nodejs backend to firebase, and followed the basic instructions to try and get things running.  Before initializing firebase functions in my app, my file structure was a basic node app:

```
|- /routes
|- /models
...
|- app.js         <-- where express "app" is initialized and my routes are brought in
|- package.json
```

I ran `firebase init functions` in my project's root directory, which made a `functions` folder at the same level as my `routes`, `models`, and other "source" folders.

```
|- /routes
...
|- /functions
    |- index.js
    |- package.json
...
|- app.js
|- package.json
```

I've been able to cd into the new functions folder and run `npm run serve` to test that the endpoint is working locally.  I can successfully make requests through postman this way.

Problem is that when trying to deploy via `npm run deploy` (in functions dir), it throws an error seemingly related to the entry file for firebase:

```
2022-09-11T18:32:03.676588Z ? app: Provided module can't be loaded.
2022-09-11T18:32:03.676627Z ? app: Did you list all required modules in the package.json dependencies?
2022-09-11T18:32:03.676656Z ? app: Detailed stack trace: Error: Cannot find module '../app'
```

my functions/package.json:

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  ...
  "main": "../app.js",
  ...
}
```

app.js:

```
...
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const app = express();
...
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

I also tried first to export `app` from app.js and require it in functions/index.js, before using the same two lines to initialize firebase in functions/index.js.  It threw a similar error, saying it couldn't find '../app'.

It seems like I may just need to change my projects structure a bit?  Is it necessary for the firebase files to live in a functions folder at all?  Do I need a separate package.json for that or can it all be in one at the root?

Comment: Why do you have multiple `package.json`? Have you tried moving all the files including routes in `/functions` and then `require("./app.js")` in `index.js`?  Also use the `package.json` that is inside `functions` and install all your dependencies there.

Comment: I'll try this.  Thank you.  I have the two separate package.json because one is from developing my app and the second came from firebase init.